# Poisson posterior PDF

Tags: bayesian, poisson-distribution, density-function, posterior

I want to understand this concept a little better, I'll give a reduced example of the problem I'm having and would appreciate a more intuitive answer (my statistics background is largely self taught so I'm missing a lot of vocabulary).

Lets say we have a board and have thrown stones onto it.  The board is divided up into squares and, before throwing any stones, I suggested a rather vague (uniform) prior that I thought each square would have between 0 and 10 stones on it (lets call this density $P$).

This, I believe, is a poisson distribution (the probability of a number of stones in a given square), let me know if I'm wrong.

Lets say we find the average number of stones is 5.

Now we want to work out the posterior probability density function and from Bayes theorem:
$$P(model|data) = \frac{P(data|model) P(model)}{P(data)}
$$
Where $P(model)$ is the flat prior of 1/10 between 0 and 10 and 0 everywhere else, $P(model|data)$ is the posterior.  How do we know the other two terms?

Comment: If the number of stones is limited to 10 at most, this cannot be a Poisson model.

Comment: @Xi'an Thank you for pointing that out but why?

Comment: It cannot be Poisson because the Poisson has a range unlimited above, so, say the probability of 1000 stones is non-zero